# Add a button to custom settings form field

Tags: magento2

I'd like to add a button on the settings form of my plugin[image]

Here the code for my input field in Vendor\App\etc\adminhtml\system.xml

```
<field id="api_key" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Api Key</label>
</field>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: which type of button you want to add?

Comment: What will be the functionality of that button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below steps to create button in magento configuration.

Step 1- Create field in [Vendor][Module]\etc\adminhtml\system.xml file

```
<field id="button_id" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Label Text</label>
        <frontend_model>[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\System\Config\Button</frontend_model>
    </field>
```

Step 2 - Create Button.php file in [Vendor][Module]\Block\System\Config

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\System\Config;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Button extends Field
{
    protected $_template = '[Vendor]_[Module]::system/config/button.phtml';

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
    public function getCustomUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('router/controller/action');
    }
    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button'
        )->setData(
            [
                'id' => 'btn_id',
                'label' => __('Button Label'),
            ]
        );
        return $button->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Step 3 - Create button.phtml file in [Vendor][Module]\view\adminhtml\templates\system\config

```
<?php $controller = $block->getCustomUrl();
      echo $block->getButtonHtml();
?>
```

Comment: I succeeded in adding the button, but I want it positioned in the same line of my input field, and on the right of it. In doing this I'm failing.

Comment: @Sukumar Gorai: the functionality of the button: send an xhttp request by javascript, then I'd like to use the response to display an innerHTML property in one of my settings' page elements. Is that possible?

Comment: @DavideIandoli Add css to that button.

Comment: Mark answer as correct & upvote it so it can help others :)